# Number of ways to rearrange in the word UNSUCCESSFULLY with the given requirements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**Question:** Given the word UNSUCCESSFULLY, calculate the number of ways to rearrange word with the given requirements below:

1. Letter 'Y' appears after all the vowels in the word?
2. The first 'S' appears before the first 'U'?
3. Both U's and L's appear consecutively at the same time?
4. C's don't appear consecutively?

Note: Each question is separate from the others.

**My attempted solution:**

For question 1, I placed the 4 vowels and the letter 'Y' first and then rearranged the word and got:
$${\binom{14}{5}} (\frac{4!}{3!})(\frac{9!}{2!2!3!3!})$$

For question 2, I did the exact same and got
$${\binom{14}{6}} (\frac{4!}{2!2!})(\frac{8!}{2!2!})$$
I'm honstly a bit confused of what the difference is between question 1 and 2. I might not be right but I used the same approach in the two answers I got above.

For question 3, I bascially combined the 2 L's and also the 3 U's and treaten them as one single letter. This resulted in the word having 11 letters. And then I got the answer:
$${\binom{11}{3}}{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{1}{1}}$$

For question 4, I caclculated the max possible ways to rearrange the letter and subtracted the ways at which three C's are together from that. I got:
$${\binom{14}{3}}{\binom{11}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{1}{1}} - {\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{9}{3}}{\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{5}{1}}{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{1}{1}}$$

I all honesty, I only followed the steps to which I think it might be correct and most of these are likely to be incorrect. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: There are $3$ U's and S's and 2 C's and L's, so there are $3!\times 3!\times2!\times2!=144$ ways to rearrange the word unsuccessfully ;)

Answer (score 3):

Total number of combinations of UNSUCCESSFULLY:

```
> factorial(14)/1/1/1/2/2/6/1/6
[1] 605404800
```

Answers:

1. First see how many combinations there are of UEUUY where Y appears last. There are 4. Choose 5 slots for it in the 14 slots. Then, rearrange the remaining 9 letters anyhow you want.

$$4*{14\choose 5}*\begin{pmatrix}9\\1,1,2,2,3\end{pmatrix}$$

```
> 4*choose(14,5)*factorial(9)/1/1/2/2/6
[1] 121080960
This is 20%.
```

2. See how many combinations of SSSUUU with the first S appearing before the first U. The possibilities are SU_ _ _ _ , SSU _ _ _ and SSSUUU. Choose 6 slots for the S's and U's. Fill in the remaining 8 slots any way you want.

$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}+3+1\right)*\begin{pmatrix}14\\6\end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}8\\1,1,1,1,2,2\end{pmatrix}$$

```
> (factorial(4)/2/+3+1)*choose(14,6)*factorial(8)/2/2
[1] 151351200
This is 25%.
```

3. I assume you meant all 3 U's appear consecutively and all 2 S's. Treating the 3 U's as one block and similarly the 2 S's, the problem reduces to.

$$\begin{pmatrix}11\\1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3\end{pmatrix}$$

```
> factorial(11)/2/6
[1] 3326400
This is roughly .549%.
```

4. This is easiest done by subtracting the number of times C's do appear consecutively from the total number of arrangements.

$$\begin{pmatrix}14\\1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}12\\1,1,1,1,2,3,3,\end{pmatrix}*13$$

```
> factorial(14)/2/2/6/6-factorial(12)/2/6/6*13
[1] 518918400
This is roughly 85.7%.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just a quick question about question 4. Why is the numerator for the second part 12 and why does the whole term have to be multiplied by 13? Would it be fine if I directly substitute the 12 with 13?

Comment: If I recall correctly my thought process was that I fixed the CC's in the first two positions and then rearranged the other 12 letters, hence the 12. Then I multiplied this by 13, by shifting the CC's one by one to the right. But you're right, directly doing it would probably be smarter, and is the same because $\begin{pmatrix}12\\1,1,1,1,2,2,3\end{pmatrix}*13=\begin{pmatrix}13\\1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

You made some errors, the reason for which I can hardly explain. So the correct answers:

Q.1
$${\binom{14}{5}} \frac{4!}{1!3!}\frac{9!}{1!1!2!2!\color{red}{3!}}$$

Q.2
$${\binom{14}{6}} \frac{\color{red}{5!}}{2!\color{red}{3!}}\frac{8!}{1!1!1!1!2!2!}$$

Q3 and Q4 are correct but it is possibly better to write:
$$
\frac{11!}{1!1!1!1!1!1!2!3!}.
$$

Note that I write all factors in the denominator. So one can easier check, that the sum of the numbers is equal to the number in numerator.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Echidna You are welcome. Do you know the reason for the errors you done?